# what occupational categories are believable during world war 2?

Tags: hollow-earth

I am making a custom pathfinder campaign that is set during world war 2 (will explain how modern becomes medieval). I need to come up with a list of occupations that the players can choose from and possible bonuses for those occupations. the setting is that the players are a group of people hand picked by allied power leaders to head to head to the north pole to find and extract the now missing admiral byrd. the players will be put on a ship and transported there. eventually being sucked into agartha AKA the hollow earth.

What I need are occupations that correspond to the classes in the pathfinder core rulebook. so barbarian, bard, cleric, druid, fighter, monk, paladin, ranger, rogue, sorcerer, and wizard.

the list of occupations I have currently are as follows:

- scientist (wizard)
- doctor (cleric)
- archeologist (druid)
- soldier (fighter)
- spy (mixed)
- linguist (bard)
- sailor (mixed)
- detective (paladin)
- stowaway (rogue)

I still need believable occupations **just for the last few classes (barbarian, ranger, sorcerer, monk)** that the allied power governments would commission during war time to go on an expedition.

Comment: Welcome to worldbuilding. You are asking us to compile an endless list, which is not the scope of this community. Please take the [tour] and visit the [help] to better understand what type of questions we answer, and if possible rework your question to fit our standards.

Comment: Most of those aren't really professions but perhaps possible broad categories of professions I believe. I'm not a linguist though ;)

Comment: If this was Britain then you might be interested in the concept of *Reserved Occupations*, Those are people who are considered essential to keep things running at home and thus are not required to be soldiers. You'll need to do your own research but here's a start. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reserved_occupation#Reserved_occupations_in_the_UK_in_World_War_II

Comment: @chaslyfromUK As an example of reserved occupations my grandfather was employed by Bedford motors making lorries prewar and then made armoured vehicles including Churchill Tanks. But  agree this is a broad list of categories not of professions rebullet00 a scientist could be a Chemist, Biologist, Geologist, Physist or any other number of disciplines. I would however suggest looking at a game like the 1920-30s set Call of Cuthulu for inspiration.

Comment: I believe this can be answered by changing the question from "professions," which are endless, and "Industries," which are not — however I can't remove the hold. There's about 25 major industries in the US classification system, all of which containly broadly related professions.